# Can BLE device connect to android wearable directly without Android Mobile

Tags: android, wear-os, ibeacon-android

Is it poosible BLE device(ibeacon) send notification to android wearable directly without going through Android Mobile?

Answer (score 0):

If by "Android Mobile" you mean phone, than yes.
You just scan devices/pair etc. via BluetoothManger as it would be a normal Android phone.

Comment: I am also looking for same scenario As mention in question connect wearable device with another BLE device and it should without paring to Mobile device. Here is my question it will help if you have anything for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262863/is-it-possible-to-connect-android-wear-device-with-another-ble-device-directly-w