# Is it possible to connect Android Wear device with another BLE device directly without interaction of phone device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, sony-smartwatch, moto-360

I am looking for an Advice to connect two BLE devices directly with each other without interference of phone device.I know that in normal scenario watch will connect with mobile device's Bluetooth and then it will work for normal data transmission process.

In my case I want this thing directly between two BLEs.I have One BLE device which is Android Watch(Sony,MOTO or ANY Android Wear) and the another is BLE belt or Strap. Now in current scenario thing are working fine if watch is paired with Mobile phone,Strap can pass data through it and watch will receive those data.

But is there anyway from that I can skip the mobile device pairing part and connect Android watch & strap directly with each other.

Your wisdom and ideas are more than welcome,thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

BLE protocol only allows the communication between a central and a peripheral device. The wristband surely is a peripheral device that advertises BLE packets and expose some services (for example the heart rate).

You need to figure out if the android watch support BLE in central mode.
In that case you will be able to scan for advertisement packets coming from peripheral devices (wristband), and connect to them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you will have to write an android wear app for your watch unless your strap has one already:-

> If you have a Bluetooth Smart accessory, open its app on your watch and follow the app's instructions to pair the accessory to your watch.

quote from [here](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6345084?hl=en-GB).

Answer (score 0):

One solution which will accomplish your request is a BLE gateway/router.  Initial pair will require computer or phone with web browser but after that you won't need the phone to connect the two although all devices would still be connected just independently, within their very own newly established ble network.