# Is it possible to connect BLE sensor device to android watch without a phone nearby?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, wear-os

Is it possible to connect BLE sensor device to android watch if the watch has BLE inside, without a phone nearby in the same manner like with a handheld device, i‘ve seen some questions on stackoverflow like this, for example

[Is it possible to connect Android Wear device with another BLE device directly without interaction of phone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262863/is-it-possible-to-connect-android-wear-device-with-another-ble-device-directly-w)

but they weren‘t answered, or the answers weren‘t clear.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BLE protocol only allows communication between a central and a peripheral device. The sensor surely is a peripheral device that advertises BLE packets and expose some services (for example the heart rate).

You need to figure out if the android watch support BLE in central mode.
In that case you will be able to scan for advertisement packets coming from peripheral devices (sensors), and connect to them.

Comment: Thanks for the response,i fixed it ,its posible as long as the watch has BLE, i used sony moto 360 2nd generation and it works like a charm without smartphone.